# validation rule needed for only numbers to be entered

Tags: c#

Hi I have a program which allows users to choose from options 1,2 and 3 which is userChoice. However when I enter a number that is higher than 3 or a letter instead of a number the program crashes or exits. I was wondering is there a validation rule that could be put in place so number 1 to 3 can only be entered.

```
     int userChoice;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Welcome();
    }


    public void Welcome()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("                       HELLO");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Main_Menu();

    }

    private void Main_Menu()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("1). Welcome");
        Console.WriteLine("2). Help Facilities");
        Console.WriteLine("3). Exit");

        string userChoiceSTR = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userChoiceSTR))
        {
            userChoice = Convert.ToInt16(userChoiceSTR); 
            try
            {
                Options();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did not put any value. Please Select a menu: ");
                Main_Menu();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did not put any value. Please Select a menu: ");
            Main_Menu();
        }
    }

    private void Options()
    {

        if (userChoice == 1)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome.....................");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        if (userChoice == 2)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Help.........................");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (userChoice == 3)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `if` statement like this:

```
...
string userChoiceSTR = Console.ReadLine();

if(userChoiceSTR != "1" && userChoiceSTR != "2" && userChoiceSTR != "3")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need to provide a value between 1 and 3");
    //Handle the case of invalid input (e.g. return)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You are checking if the user entered some value or not. But you are not checking if it is integer or not. You need to make sure he entered integer. Move the Convert statement inside the try block.

```
            try
            {
                userChoice = Convert.ToInt16(userChoiceSTR); 
                Options();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did not put valid value. Please Select a menu: ");
                Main_Menu();
            }
```

Now you need to make sure he entered between 1 and 3. In your senario, I will suggest using switch case.

```
private void Options()
{

    switch(userChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome.....................");
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Help.........................");
            Console.ReadLine();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            //Code to handle other values.
            break;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse instead of the Convert method to validate for numeric entry. If the user input is not a number, it will not throw an exception. Instead, it will return a boolean value of false. For example,

```
//Declare the boolean variable:
bool input = false;

string string1 = "";

//Get the user input and attempt to parse to an int:
string1 = Console.Readline();
input = int.TryParse(string1, out num1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Int32.TryParse method could be used.  It would ensure that valid answers like "02" were converted to integers and handled appropriately.

```
int number;
if(Int32.TryParse(userChoiceSTR, out number) &&
    number > 0 && number <= 3)
{
    Options();
}
else
{
    // Handle incorrect user choices  
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx